# How to trigger a browser download from a browser FETCH?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, csv, fetch-api

I'm working on a project with **Vue.js** and **Typescript** for front-end and **Java Spring** as backend.

My java controller retrieves a given report from the db and then copies it into the HTML response. 
I want the CSV to be downloaded by the browser therefore I added *Content-disposition* header in the  response.

```java
     @GetMapping('/download')
     public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest response){
        Report r = reportService.findById(85);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myCSV.csv");
        response.setContentType("text/csv");

        try {
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getDocument());
            IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch(Exception e) {...}
     }
```

I have 2 buttons: one simple hyperlink tag with href linking to *download()*, and a b-button (from bootstrap-vue) that once cliccked triggers *download2()*.

```html
   <a :href="download" role="button"> Download CSV </a>

   <b-button @click="event => download2()">
      Download CSV v2
   </b-button>
```

```js
    get download(): string {
        return 'http://localhost:8080/download';
    }


    async download2() {
        const rHeaders = new Headers();
        rHeaders.append('Accept', 'text/csv');

        const configInit = RequestInit = {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: rHeaders
        };

        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/download', configInit);
            return res.text();
        } catch (e) {...}
    }
```

Now, If I click on the first button "Download csv", the csv is correctly downloaded by the browser. The javascript console prints the following:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv
```

and there is nothing in the response body.

Instead, if I click the 2nd button "Download csv v2", the download does not start but I have the csv in the response body.

Here, the differences in the request headers between the two.

```
*Header*                   *Download csv*        *Download csv v2*
Sec-Fetch-Dest                document               empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode                navigate               cors
Sec-Fetch-User                   ?1                    -
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests        1                     -
```

the other headers are the same. It is not possible to change these headers, even if I set them in the javascript method; they remain still the same.
What's the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Just a thought : what makes you think the response is different? The browser behaves differently, but after all, clicking a HTML <a> hyper link vs. launching an asyncrhonous request (AJAX style) are different beasts altogether. Have you actually observed (say, from the network inspector of your browser) that the responses are different ?

Comment: @GPI you're right, I put it badly.  The responses are basically the same (all headers are equal), except that one (the first) is of type "document" and the other is "fetch" type (from network inspector). The behaviour of the browser changes. I would like to figure out why, in fact they are both GET requests.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I therefore suggest you rephrase your question entirely,

Comment: Because your issue seems to be browser related and not backend related. It’s not the spring / java part that is in question but rather how to trigger a browser download from a browser fetch

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @GPI, I'll rephrase it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by "mimicking" the behavior of a `<a>` element:

This way, it works properly:

```js
async download2() {
    const configInit: RequestInit = {
        method: 'GET'
    };

    try {
       await fetch('http://localhost:8080/download', configInit)
          .then(response => response.blob())
          .then(blob => {
              const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              const a = document.createElement('a');
              a.style.display = 'none';
              a.href = url;
              a.download = 'report.csv';
              document.body.appendChild(a);
              a.click();
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          })
    } catch (e) {...}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for big files as the binary is kept stored in memory until the download finishes